# Strange "Unresolved reference:" error after upgrading to Kotlin 1.0.5

Tags: kotlin

I have a project that contains 2 modules. A Java module that contains my java code. And a Kotlin module that contains my Kotlin code. The Kotlin module depends on the java module. That is, there is nothing in the Java module that references the Kotlin module. But the Kotlin module relies on Java classes from the Java module.

This project I haven't opened for 6 months or so.

It worked fine before. It was kotlin 1.something. Whatever was the latest in June.

Now I have updated to the latest Kotlin version.

But one of my java module java classes cannot be referenced anymore from the Kotlin module. It is only 1 of the classes, the Kotlin module references a lot of other classes from the Java module just fine still.

I am hoping someone can tell me what is going on. Maybe there were some changes to Kotlin in the last 6 months that cause this?

The message I get in all Kotlin files in the Kotlin module that reference JSBot is this:

```
Error:(191, 39) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JSBot
```

The JSBot import in the kt files is correct. Other classes from the Java module even in the same java package are recognized and compile without errors.

Here is the JSBot.java declaration (in the java module):

```
public abstract class JSBot extends Evaluable implements Name {
...
}
```

Other abstract java classes are referenced fine though from the Kotlin module. So I can't really understand what is going on. It is just this one Java class.

But, in earlier Kotlin versions (v1.0 through whatever was latest in June) it compiled fine. I just get this error now. I haven't changed any code. Only updated to kotlin plugin 1.0.5

Could anyone give me some hints what to do? I am stuck and can't figure out where to go from here.

I updated my maven .pom to 1.0.5 from 1.0.0, but that didn't help.

Comment: Does the JSBot class have inner classes with annotations on their constructor parameters?

Comment: It has 2 inner classes `public final class Orders` which has its own inner class `protected final class OpenOrders` , however neither of these have constructors. I do however annotate all my methods and constructors (when there are constructors) with `@Nullable` or `@NotNull` annotations. And the other inner class is `public abstract class Order` which does contain a constructor `public Order(@NotNull PlacedOrder placedOrder)`- so yes it seems that this 2nd inner class is such an inner class with annotations in the constructor parameters as you asked about

Comment: I just removed this `@NotNull` and yes it does compile now without the *unresolved reference* error for `JSBot`... so, is this the *fix* ? will future kotlin versions still have this problem?

Comment: The issue will be fixed in either Kotlin 1.0.6 or a hotfix update to Kotlin 1.0.5.

Comment: great, thanks . I had about 5 of these classes I needed to "fix". Now they all compile, but would be nice to be able to put the annotations back in later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be *resolved*, issue will be fixed in Kotlin release described in comments above. Please don't delete this question, it might be helpful to others that encounter this kotlin bug.